# "Nominal" vs. "minimal"

Tags: synonyms

Has "nominal" really become a synonym for "minimal"? I thought "nominal" meant "in name only," but it appears that the definition has evolved. What say the members of this esteemed group?

Comment: Are you referring to this meaning? ***Nominal***:  Insignificantly small; *trifling: a nominal sum* . ***Nominal***  (of a price, fee, etc.) named as a matter of form, being trifling in comparison with the actual value: a nominal price.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nominal

Answer (score 1):

Nominal does not mean minimal. In many financial cases, a "nominal" payment means that a trivial amount has been given, not for its value, which is insignificant, but because the payment marks the retention or resolution of a contractual structure. Because a nominal amount is small does not mean it is minimal.

I might pay a nominal amount of £1000 for the purchase of an unwanted factory worth hundreds of thousands of pounds. The payment is nominal rather than minimal but it concludes a contract of transfer of ownership.

Similarly, in Scotland, I used to pay a nominal penny per year to the original owner of my land. The payment was nominal rather than minimal (no pence) but marked the retention of an ancient legal relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Well, synonyms are seldom exact, but yes, in some contexts "nominal" is used to mean "minimal".

As you say, "nominal" means "in name only", while "minimal" means "the least possible".  So, if you start with the minimum amount of something required to call it by a certain name, and then you take away a little more, you can't call it by that name anymore.  There's no longer even a "nominal" amount of whatever it was.